# I can't find the right driver for ASUS laptop webcam on Windows 7 x64

Tags: laptop, drivers, webcam

The picture of the webcam on my ASUS K51AE/K70AE laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium x64 is upside down. I probably haven't got the right driver installed. The Hardware ID of the webcam is

> USB\VID_04F2&PID_B071&REV_1515&MI_00

I can't find a driver for this, the asus website doesn't yield any results when I search for it. Can someone give me the correct website with the right driver?

Comment: You may have the right driver... should be a settings in the Codec or the software itself. Been there, done that. Take a look and let me know.

Comment: I've got Microsoft drivers, no ASUS drivers. "Update drivers" in the device manager says they are up to date, but I read in some forums that I need an ASUS driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Asus's support download page (under Camera) for the K51AE](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=196&m=K51AE&os=&hashedid=qBACWQERnT4xxHj6), for Windows 7 64-bit:

> Chicony CNF-7129 Camera Driver for Win7 64 bit (V061.005.200.260)
>
> This driver is for below PID code:
>
> HardwareID=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b028&MI_00
>
> HardwareID2=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b036&MI_00
>
> HardwareID3=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b029&MI_00
>
> **HardwareID4=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b071&MI_00**
>
> HardwareID5=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b034&MI_00
>
> HardwareID6=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b106&MI_00
>
> HardwareID7=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b141&MI_00
>
> HardwareID8=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b140&MI_00
>
> HardwareID9=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b13a&MI_00
>
> HardwareID10=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b16B&MI_00
>
> HardwareID11=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b16E&MI_00
>
> HardwareID12=USB\Vid_04f2&Pid_b189&MI_00

That looks like your camera PID to me, hopefully it'll help. :)